# Prevent Mac OS App window from stealing focus - Swift/Cocoa (GitHub Repo)

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, window, focus

*This is an open-source OS X app which displays lyrics of a song currently playing in a Music Player...
https://github.com/ddddxxx/LyricsX*

It creates an NSScrollview/NSTextview window which displays lyrics, with this piece of code (correct me if i'm wrong) -
https://github.com/ddddxxx/LyricsX/blob/master/LyricsX/View/ScrollLyricsView.swift

> The issue is, when the said Lyrics Window is placed in a Space
> (Mission Control), the window will steal focus whenever you swipe to
> another space (two finger swipe via mouse/trackpad or keyboard
> shortcut) it will cause you to revert back to space containing the
> Lyrics Window.
>
> For example, if the lyrics window is on "Desktop 1" and you swipe to
> "Desktop 2", the system will immediately switch back to "Desktop 1"
> and bring the lyrics window in focus.

I'm quite new to Swift/Cocoa so I would love some help figuring out how to make sure the Lyrics window is NEVER in focus. I wouldn't mind outright disabling focus of the window entirely.

*PS. Is this piece of code interfering/causing this behavior?
https://github.com/ddddxxx/LyricsX/blob/master/LyricsX/Controller/AutoActivateWindowController.swift*

Comment: I'm getting alittle desperate with this, I'd really love it if someone could help.
Maybe a reward would help? We can talk on my Discord if anyone wants...

Comment: Still nobody can help me figure it out?